# How to link a Vuetify <v-card> to an external website?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vue-router, nuxtjs

How to link a `v-card` to an external website ?

When I'm doing this:

```
<v-card to="https://www.stackoverflow.com">
  <v-card-title>STACK OVERFLOW</v-card-title>
</v-card>
```

It's redirecting to:

```
http://localhost:3000/https://www.stackoverflow.com
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`to` prop is used to redirect to vue router path, if you want to redirect to an external link you could use `href` instead with `target="_blank"` if you want to open the link in new tab :

```
 <v-card href="https://www.stackoverflow.com" target="_blank">
```

Answer (score 2):

You're using the wrong attribute, you should be using the `href` attribute like this which will denote the element as an anchor (`a`) tag:

```
<v-card href="https://www.stackoverflow.com">
  <v-card-title>STACK OVERFLOW</v-card-title>
</v-card>
```